# If $f(x) =x^{x^{x^{x}}}$, determine the last two digits of $f(17) + f(18) + f(19) + f(20).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If 
$$  f(x)= x^{x^{x^x}}, $$

then calculate the last two digits of $\displaystyle f(17) +  f(18) +  f(19) + f(20).$

I know that last two digits of $ f(20)$ will be $00$ and I also tried to find the last two digits by binomial coefficients,

like for $ 19^{19} ,$ we can get the last digit by : $$ {19 \choose 1} \times 20 - 1 $$ will be equal to $79$. Here I expresses $19$ as $20-1$ but for the next step I would need the value of $ 19^{19} $ and that would not be worth it !

Please help me, and tell me some good method to do  such type of questions.

Thank you in advance. Please help me out with the tags. I do not know under which section it should come.

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler's theorem?

Comment: Euler's Phi function ?

Comment: modular arithmetic?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with it

Comment: The $\phi$ ("totient") function does feature prominently in Euler's theorem, yes. But I wouldn't say that the theorem is _about_ the function, per se.

Comment: So what is the theorem ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem You need the Chinese remainder theorem as well, though. In particular to deal with $f(18)$, but I might suggest you use it on the others as well.

Comment: I tried to understand it but it was complicated, do you have any good source ?

Comment: What is Inverse of modulo ? Why do we define it ? In the proof of Chinese remainder theorem, it is required.

Comment: We'd like to solve the congruence $ax\equiv b\pmod{c}$  as $x\equiv a^{-1}b\pmod{c}$, so we need $a^{-1}$.  It's defined as the number that makes the congruence $a\cdot a^{-1}\equiv1\pmod{c}$ true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be having trouble following the hints given in the comments, I'll give a more extensive explanation.

In order to evaluate $$19^{19^{19^{19}}}\pmod{100}$$ we first want to find the smallest exponent $e$ such that $$19^e\equiv1\pmod{100}$$  Then if $n$ is a positive integer, we can write $n=me+k$ for integers $m$ and $k$, where $0\leq k<e$, so that 
$$19^n=19^{me}\cdot19^k=\left(19^e\right)^m\cdot19^k\equiv1^m\cdot19^k\equiv19^k\pmod{100}$$

We know $\phi(100)=40$, so by Euler's theorem, $19^{40}\equiv1\pmod{100}$, and the smallest exponent must divide $40$.  We find by experiment that the smallest exponent that works is $10.$  (Even though your calculator may not be able to compute $19^{10}$ directly, you only have to retain the last two digits as you compute higher powers, so this is not a problem.  You can shortcut the work by repeatedly squaring, and multiplying appropriate powers of $2$.)

Anyway, now we need to know the value of $19^{19^{19}}$ modulo $10$.  We do the same thing as before, only we work modulo $10$ instead of modulo $100$ this time.  It's clear that $19^2\equiv1\pmod{10}$ so $2$ is the smallest exponent.  Now we know $19^{19}$ is odd, so $$19^{19^{19}}\equiv19^1\equiv9\pmod{10},$$ and 
$$19^{19^{19^{19}}}\equiv19^9\pmod{100}$$

If you've saved the powers of $19$ from when you figured out $19^{10}\equiv1\pmod{100}$, you can easily compute that $$19^9\equiv79\pmod{100}$$

When we try to apply this method to $18^{18^{18^{18}}}$, we run into the problem that Euler's theorem doesn't apply, since $18$ and $100$ are not relatively prime.  I see however that Robert Israel has just posted an answer explaining that case, so I'll stop here.

Comment: There must be an edit in last third paragraph '

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi I found where I typed "modulo $0$" instead of "modulo$10$".  Was that it, or is there another mistake?

Comment: No, it's perfect, but how $ 19^{19^{19} } \equiv 9 \pmod {10}$ can we say it in general. That if $ {a^a} \equiv 1 \pmod n $ then $ a^{a^a} \equiv a \pmod n$ ?

Comment: We know that $19^2\equiv1\pmod{10}$ so in computing power of $19$ modulo $10$ we only need to know if the exponent is even or odd.  $19^{2n+1}=19^{2n}\cdot19^1\equiv1\cdot19\equiv9\pmod{10}$

Comment: First we tried to find modulo $10$ to determine the first digit,  then modulo $100$ for last two digits... am I right ?

Comment: If we want three digit then, for $10, 100 $ and $1000$ ?

Comment: You would start out with $1000$.  There's no telling what the next moduli would be.  It happened that the exponent of $19$ was $10$.  That isn't the case for $17$.

Comment: Why you chose smallest power $10$ that would divide $19^{40}$ ? why not $2$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105092/discussion-between-nikola-alfredi-and-saulspatz).

Comment: I chose the smallest exponent $e$ such that $19^e\equiv1\pmod{100}$.  I explained why in the answer.  I could have used $40$ instead of $10$, but it's usually easier to work with smaller numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For example, let's consider $f(18)$.  It's easy to see $f(18) \equiv 0 (\mod 4)$.  What about mod $25$?  Well, $\phi(25) = 20$, so let's consider $18^{18^{18}} \mod 20$.
Again, $18^{18^{18}} \equiv 0 \mod 4$, so let's consider it mod $5$. $\phi(5) = 4$, and $18^{18} \equiv 0 \mod 4$, so $18^{18^{18}} \equiv 1 \mod 5$.  By Chinese Remainder,
$18^{18^{18}} \equiv 16 \mod 20$. So $f(18) \equiv 18^{16} \equiv 1 \mod 25$. Again by Chinese Remainder, since $f(18) \equiv 0 \mod 4$ and  $f(18) \equiv 1 \mod 25$, 
$f(18) \equiv 76 \mod 100$.